# error: cannot find symbol method setSupportImageTintList(ColorStateList)

Tags: java, android

I have tried to use the method `setSupportImageTintList` to add to wishlist, but I am getting an error. This method was used in a video tutorial. I just need to know why I can't use the method.

I tried to find solution in Google. There is no such link with setSupportImageTintList.

```
addToWishlistBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ALREADY_ADDED_TO_WISHLIST){
                ALREADY_ADDED_TO_WISHLIST = false;
                addToWishlistBtn.setSupportImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#9e9e9e")));
            }else{
                ALREADY_ADDED_TO_WISHLIST = true;
                addToWishlistBtn.setSupportImageTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
        }
    });
```

There is not much data about this error on Google. So kindly provide the details about the method and why can't I use themethod. Thank you

Comment: If you get an error, you should post it to help clarify and resolve the problem. Anyway .setSupportImageTintList is probably a method of FloatingActionButton, which inherits it from TintableImageSourceView. The method doc says "Applies a tint to the image drawable. Does not modify the current tint mode, which is PorterDuff.Mode#SRC_IN by default." where the argument is the tint to apply. I suppose that this method change the appearance of the button. https://www.androidx.de/androidx/core/widget/TintableImageSourceView.html#setSupportImageTintList-ColorStateList-

Answer (score 0):

you have to import this package

```
androidx.appcompat.widget
```

add this implementation to your app gradle dependecies

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
```